# Powershell で MailKit を使用するには？

Tags: powershell

PowershellでMailKitを利用したいのですが、何のDLLファイルをインストールする必要があるのでしょうか。
現在下記のMailKitのバージョンをAdd-Pathしようとしておりますが、エラーが発生します。

```
$MimeKit = "C:\Program Files\PackageManagement\NuGet\Packages\MimeKit.3.2.0\lib\net47\MimeKit.dll"
$MailKit = "C:\Program Files\PackageManagement\NuGet\Packages\MailKit.3.2.0\lib\net47\MailKit.dll"
Add-Type -Path $MimeKit
Add-Type -Path $MailKit
```

Comment: こんな記事が参考になるかもしれません。[PowerShellでJISコードのメールを送信する (MailKit編) (1)](https://nkurilog.blogspot.com/2021/10/powershelljis-mailkit-1.html)